# PROLOG.NET - Connect to Database

Tags: .net, sql, ado.net, prolog

I'm using [Prolog.NET](http://prolog.hodroj.net) and I want to query an SQL Database, but I don't want to use an OBDC connection.

It's possible connect to a database using ADO.NET or something like that (since I'm using PROLOG.NET)?